# npx expo run:android -> CommandError: No development build (<package>) for this project is installed

Tags: react-native, expo

After running `npx expo run:android` once, the app was pushed to the device and the app started up.

I then uninstalled the app on the device and then when I run `npx expo run:android` once again I get the error:

```
CommandError: No development build (<package-name>) for this project is installed. Please make and install a development build on the device first.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/development/build/
```

I started another dummy project with another package name and the same thing can be reproduced after uninstalling once.
The built app is not installing once again on the Android device and then starting up.

The docs referenced in the error states https://docs.expo.dev/development/build/#locally-with-xcode-and-android-studio the following:

> If you are comfortable setting up Xcode, Android Studio, and related dependencies, you can build and distribute your app the same as any other iOS or Android app.
> The npx expo run commands will create a new build, install it on to your emulator or device, and start running it.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must run `eas build` again with your device emulator opened. When the command finishes running, it'll ask if you want to install it in the emulator

Comment: This can't possibly be the only way

Answer (score 0):

open expo from the emulator and start the application.
it will start rebuilding

or

npx expo install expo-dev-client

then use "eas build --local" || npx expo run:[android|ios]